# mod_rewrite if file in subdirectory does not exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have never used `mod_rewrite` before, so I am struggling with setting up a proper rules for my use case.

I have a URL looking like that: `domain.com/pict/123456`
directory structure is like so:

`/pict/
  |-- autogenerated/
    |-- 12345.png
    |-- 87654.png
  |-- gen.php
  |-- .htaccess`

and what I'd like to achieve is:

If `12345.png` does not exist in `autogenerated`, 
rewrite URL to `gen.php?id=12345`

else serve the `autogenerated/12345.png` file

I have tried various solutions found on the internet (as well as most of Stackoverflow answers - all to no avail).

my `.htaccess` file looks like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond autogenerated/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.png -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  autogenerated/$1.png  [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ generate.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]


</IfModule>
```

I have also tried changing the `RewriteCond` like so:

`RewriteCond autogenerated/$1.png -f`

`RewriteCond autogenerated/%{REQUEST_URI}.png -f`

`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/autogenerated/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.png -f`

`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/autogenerated/$1.png -f`

`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pict/autogenerated/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.png -f`

`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pict/autogenerated/$1.png -f`

and no matter what I do, first RewriteRule never triggers, and everything is sent to the `gen.php`

am I missing anything here?

Comment: Both REQUEST_FILENAME and REQUEST_URI contain the path information. // Where is your htaccess file located, in the root or the pict folder?

Comment: oh. I thought that REQUEST_FILENAME contains only what's after last "/"

my `htaccess` file is inside "pict" folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rules like this inside `pict/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pict/

# if image file exists inside pict/autogenerated/ 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pict/autogenerated/$1.png -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ autogenerated/$1.png [L]

# else rewrite to generate.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ generate.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: you're a star! thanks a lot :)
still don't get why it didn't work for me and setting `RewriteBase` did make it work, tough... o_O